# Failed to run Angular5

Tags: linux, angular

I installed one Angular5 followed the guide on Angular website, but I cannot get nothing when I run ng -v
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eeviw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj84m.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFSP2.png)

The warning said that no such ‘node’ file in usr/bin/env, but I can find my installed angular in the path usr/local/lib/node_moudles. What is wrong with it, should I remove all npm plugin and reinstall them again(or change to the right directory)?

Comment: What guide did you follow exactly, and what steps did you take to try and install all this?

Comment: like this one http://www.uday.net/How-to-Install-Latest-Nodejs-%26-Npm-Angular2-Typescript-on-Ubuntu-16.04  I used the sudo command line in it

Comment: You need to update node to at least 6.9. See [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#prerequisites) for Angular CLI installation details. [This](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) could be helpful, too.

Comment: The actual steps I took are (1) install nodejs (2)npm (3)nodemon (4)angular, then I found this problem

Comment: I just run sudo apt-get install nodejs again, it said my nodejs is the newest version 4.2.6

Comment: Try going to nodejs.org and see if there is a way to install a newer version on your OS. 4.2.6 won't work for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete whatever you did, and start from an empty enviroment with the [Angular official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).
2. Make sure to install the correct versions (see in the documentation for current requirements) of node and npm
3. Make sure to install Angular cli globally. (-g)
4. Make sure to `cd <folder-name>` into the folder you create with `ng new` before trying to start anything.

Answer (score 0):

Install angular cli globally using the command 'npm install -g @angular/cli'